# cv2.aruco.detectMarkers doesn't detect markers in python

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

My camera calibration and distortion matrixes, obtained from **aruco_calibration_fromimages.exe**:

```
 [[3.19439125e+03   0.00000000e+00   1.98509417e+03]  
  [0.00000000e+00   3.20213561e+03   1.55099552e+03]  
  [0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]

 [[0.1395281  -0.38313647  0.00505558  0.00237535  0.33952515]]
```

Image, where I try to detect:

[image]

**aruco_simple.exe** succeeds

[image]

But python code fails to find anything:

```
fs = cv2.FileStorage("./calib_asus_chess/cam_calib_asus.yml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
cam_mat=fs.getNode("camera_matrix").mat()
dist_mat=fs.getNode("distortion_coefficients").mat()
gray=cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\steve\\Dropbox\\Projects\\kinnekt\\laser\\aruco_frames\\shot1.jpg',0)
adict = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL)
res = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(gray,dictionary=adict,cameraMatrix=cam_mat,distCoeff=dist_mat)
```

res[0] is empty array for some reason. Why python version fails? Thanx!

Comment: To be honest, I tried all the flags named `cv2.aruco.DICT_XXX`, the results stayed the same. All are wrong.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but the paper looks (not sure) like it's not flat on the table. This will hurt your calibration result accuracy ...

Comment: C++ aruco detects markers properly on this pic

Answer (score 7):

You are probably using a dictionary that does not correspond to your image. According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html) cv2.aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL is 5x5:

> DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL: standard ArUco Library Markers. 1024 markers, 5x5 bits, 0 minimum distance

Your image has 6x6 icons instead of 5x5, this is why it doesn't work.

You could use the function drawMarker() to draw some markers of the dictionary in an image and then print them and use them for your test.

For example, [here](http://jevois.org/moddoc/DemoArUco/modinfo.html) you can [download DICT_4X4_50 icons](http://jevois.org/data/ArUco.zip). You can print them and change your code to use DICT_4X4_50 instead of DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL